# Rails server command problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a macbook pro os 10.6.6. When running rails server and load http://0.0.0.0:3000 the page tries to load for awhile then gives a "connection has timed out error". Has anyone had this problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

<del>You're probably hitting another computer in your local network.</del> See ↓.

Try http://localhost:3000/.

You can also try your actual IP address which you'll find in System Preferences > Network.

Comment: Close, but not quite there: 0.0.0.0 isn't a valid IP address. What this actually is indicating is that the server is listening on all interfaces and not just a specific one. Your suggestion to try localhost:3000 is a spot-on solution though.

Comment: Trying my local host still results in the same thing. Using my IP address just quickly loads can't establish connection with server.

Comment: @themacguy234 What does your terminal say after you run `rails server`? Or are you running rails 2.X?

Comment: My terminal has no errors. It just says the standard webrick... etc. I have never seen this problem before. I have just switched to a new macbook pro so I am not sure if there is anything different than a pc.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure webrick is running. You should see a ruby process when you execute the following command.

  ps aux | grep rails
- Make sure webrick is listening on your localhost.

  sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"

You should see something like

```
ruby      5710         username    7u  IPv4 0x12d3b680      0t0    TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

as the output. If you don't see it webrick is not running.

- You can try running a different web server ie: ./script/server webrick instead of the default mongrel