# Rails server command generates error report

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04

When I used `rails server` command, found following errors in terminal. It shows that "could not find a JavaScript runtime". I am newbie in ROR and don't know to configure different files. I Google and found solutions of this problem [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356171/ruby-on-rails-error-running-rails-s-command) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643229/rails-server-command-problem) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633696/ruby-on-rails-server-command). Still I am not getting the things. Please suggest some solutions.

[image]

Ruby and Rail versions on my system

Ruby version:- ruby 1.8.7 ,   Rails version:- Rails 3.2.6

Comment: This problem is not seems like an easy task for newbie. For what basis it got negative vote.......?

Comment: I think this is not a bad question at all so I voted it up again. although you might want to search a little in the future the solution to this is everywhere. still have fun learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you lack executable on your system/

Haven't you try to run `gem install execjs` or `bundle install`(from your project directory) in console?

**UPDATE**

Also visit [execjs homepage](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) and try instaling any of JS runtimes supported.

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to reproduce your error (with ruby 1.9.2). Just add `gem 'therubyracer'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`. For some weird reason ROR is not working out of the box on Ubuntu. See [this](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html) and search for *runtime* word for more info.

PS

Please put your Gemfile here. This might help.

Comment: so, have you try to install JS runtime? E.g. ```sudo gem install therubyracer```

Comment: dude it still gave error..... By using this gem it installed therubyracer (0.10.1)

Comment: I've update my answer. Looks like I figure out what was wrong. And, yes (thanks to Ganesh), use 1.9.3. 1.8.7 is deprecated and not will be supported in upcoming version of rails.

Answer (score 0):

The error message also tells your to

> See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

You have to install one of the JavaScript runtimes listed there:

- [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer)
- [therubyrhino](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyrhino)
- [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
- [Microsoft Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3.2.6 I suggest to use Ruby 1.9.3. for better performance.